# Linking external style is not working

Tags: css, hyperlink

I have been trying this in any possible way, I can not figure out what is wrong here.
Here is my code
http://jsbin.com/xeroborohe/edit?html,output

and this is how I link my css

```
<link rel='stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://aa4d96bd21c195e7b862b851b0818e89fb8ee102.googledrive.com/host/0B77cxO0Vjbb2MlYyUFpmVXhTUWc/knowledgetree.css" />
```

For some reasons the line that links to the Google drive stored style sheet is not working,. I ahve also tried to link the file locally on my drive..no luck

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

window.toggleDiv = function(divId) {
  var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
  var state=jQuery(ele).is(':visible');
  jQuery(ele).toggle();
  state=jQuery(ele).is(':visible');
  localStorage.setItem( divId, state);  
}


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($){
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".collapsible").each(function(index) {
                      if (typeof($(this).attr('id'))!="undefined") {
                        id=$(this).attr('id');
                        var state = localStorage.getItem(id);
                        ele = document.getElementById(id);
                        if (state=="true") {
                          ele.style.display = 'block' ;}
                        else {
                          ele.style.display = 'none'; }

                      }
                      });
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://aa4d96bd21c195e7b862b851b0818e89fb8ee102.googledrive.com/host/0B77cxO0Vjbb2MlYyUFpmVXhTUWc/knowledgetree.css" />

    <a class="ConceptLevel1" href="javascript:toggleDiv('PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==');" style="font-

size:13pt">Root</a><br>
    <div class="collapsible" style="display:none " id="PktS/h+L5EeSqM/4hMH9JA==">
        <a class="ConceptLevel2" href="javascript:toggleDiv('KlHtq+Xe60essn+0zs9E6g==');" style="font-

size:12pt">level 1</a><br>
        <div class="collapsible" style="" id="KlHtq+Xe60essn+0zs9E6g==">
            <div>Level 2</div>
            <a class="ConceptLevel3" href="javascript:toggleDiv('EdMUp+28okWIWHVbvUaU1g==');" style="font-

size:11pt">Level 2</a><br>
            <div class="collapsible" style="" id="EdMUp+28okWIWHVbvUaU1g==">
                <a class="ConceptLevel4" href="javascript:toggleDiv('wIZCSCx/Xk2YShMAkF33Pg==');" 

style="font-size:10pt">Level 3</a><br>
                <div class="collapsible" style="" id="wIZCSCx/Xk2YShMAkF33Pg==">
                    <div>Level 4</div>
                    <a class="ConceptLevel5" href="javascript:toggleDiv('7GKbN5XRqkybT

+XsbHkyqw==');" style="font-size:9pt">Level 4</a><br>
                    <div class="collapsible" style="" id="7GKbN5XRqkybT+XsbHkyqw==">
                        <div>Level 5</div>
                        <a class="ConceptLevel6" href="javascript:toggleDiv

('rV75pTUXp0KP6Mx6EJznDg==');" style="font-size:8pt">Level 5</a><br>
                        <div class="collapsible" style="display:none " 

id="rV75pTUXp0KP6Mx6EJznDg==">
                        <div class="details">Conclusion: for all the below levels ....</div>
                            <a class="ConceptLevel7" href="javascript:toggleDiv

('a5qCUDoqI0CPlS4pPGcODQ==');" style="font-size:7pt">Level 6</a><br>
                            <div class="collapsible" style="" 

id="a5qCUDoqI0CPlS4pPGcODQ==">
                                <div>Level 7</div>
                                <div>Level 7</div>
                            </div>
                            <div>Level 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>Level 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Update: I have fixed the link, now it leads to a css file  https://aa4d96bd21c195e7b862b851b0818e89fb8ee102.googledrive.com/host/0B77cxO0Vjbb2MlYyUFpmVXhTUWc/knowledgetree.css

Comment: `rel='stylesheet"` should be `rel="stylesheet"`. Look at the syntax-highlighting.

Comment: `rel='stylesheet"` Mixing quotes can cause issues. And in general stylesheets should be linked *before* scripting.

Comment: the jsbin code is correctly using " not ' . The above was due a last minute attempt to fix things

Comment: @Scott: I tried that too (placing the style at the top of my file) .it did not work

Comment: You can't link to files in Google Drive. That's not what it's for and Google blocks that kind of usage.

Comment: The answer previously posted and deleted was actually correct: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B77cxO0Vjbb2dk5GQmxvWGMxS3c` redirects to an HTML page, not a CSS file.

Comment: I tried on my local web site, the above was an attempt to test it online  without having my own public website. I followed this guide http://www.komku.org/2013/08/how-to-host-javascript-or-css-files-on-google-drive.html

Comment: @xufox -where can I store a css file online so I can have a working jsbin?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a single quote followed by double quotes in the first attribute in your html tag (the one you link your css with).

Try keeping an eye on your syntax coloring. Stackoverflow already does this.
Try using an IDE("Integrated Development Environment" or code assisting text editor), like Notepad++, Atom, Sublime Text 3, etc. 
Google "top 10 ide's".

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing, mostly for me (a programmer by night) but it should be more for the pro who rushed to sanction my typos or what they believed it would be typos.

I was using ConceptLevel in the html code and conceptlevel in css
I am wondering why jsbin worked with this